Customize transformer in microsoft fabric evenstream processor
I'm using eventstream in microsoft fabric to transfer data from kafka to kql database. Now I want to add some customize transformation which is not mentioned in default transformation processor.
Here is showing default operator.

How can I use customize transformation like make column to row.
I also get same question but no solution there.

The easiest way today is to land the stream in a KQL Database table, and then use an Update Policy to transform it using KQL into the desired format.
Custom EventStream transformations are on the roadmap.  You can also introduce an Azure Function with EventHub bindings between two EventStreams.
